# Prove that $\ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \{(1-\frac{z}{n})^{nk} \exp(\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}) \}$ converges absolutely.

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, absolute-convergence

Prove that $\forall z,\ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \{(1-\frac{z}{n})^{nk} \exp(\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}) \}$ where $k$ is a positive integer, converges absolutely.

It seems to me $(1-\frac{z}{n})^{nk}\rightarrow e^{-kz}$, and so the infinite product approximates $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{\exp(-kz) \exp(\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}) \right\}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{(n^{k-1}-k)z+\dots},$$

> which when $k > 1$ diverges for $z\in\{z, |z|>1\}$, by the ratio test of $\frac{|((n+1)^{k-1}-k)z|}{|(n^{k-1}-k)z|}.$ [edit: this is incorrect, since this power of z (as well as *all other powers* of z, i.e. m, which depends only on k) is independent of the 'independent variable of the series' n.]

which we from the ratio test we see equals an infinite series $\sum u_n$ with $\frac{|u_{n+1}|} {|u_n|}\rightarrow 1.$

Then by expanding $\frac{|u_{n+1}|} {|u_n|}$ as 1+A/n+O(1/n$^2$), we have A=k-1>-1, ($\sum$ n$^{k-1}$ converges not,) so the infinite product doesn't converge.

My question:

1. is the step
   'the infinite product approximates $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \{\exp(-kz) \exp(\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}) \}$'  valid?
2. Is my conclusion about convergence or not correct? I guess not. If so, where does the proof go wrong?

---

*Edited to add:*

As pointed out in the answer, the original problem is about
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \{(1-\frac{z}{n})^{n^k} \exp(\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}) \}.$$

Comment: You shouldn't do anything of that sort at the first step.  Instead, apply the definition of convergent infinite product, then you could think of approximating with control on the error.

Comment: Would you like to explain why we can't do that in the beginning? Or perhaps is there any theorem or example shows that similar method is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing $(1-z/n)^{n\color{gray}{k}}$ with $e^{-\color{gray}{k}z}$ is *not* valid, since the difference of logarithms of these is $k$ times $$n\log\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)+z=-\frac{z^2}{2n}+\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$$ as $n\to\infty$ with $z$ fixed, thus it introduces a divergence of harmonic type $\color{LightGray}{\left[\sum_n 1/n\right]}$ (if $z\neq 0$).

The original claim is wrong as well. Most probably, there's a typo; a fixed version would ask for $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left\{\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)^{\color{red}{n^k}}\exp\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}\right\}.$$

In all the cases, the approach is to take logs and taylor-expand. For a fixed $z$, and $n$ large enough, $$n^k\log\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)+\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}=-\sum_{m=k+2}^\infty\frac{n^{k-m}z^m}{m}=\mathcal{O}(n^{-2}).$$

Comment: Yes, there is a typo.